# What is the opposite of "to adopt"?

Tags: antonyms

When you take a child from an orphanage, you `adopt` him.
What do parents do when they give him away?

And I mean volunterily, not in "child services confiscation" kind of way.

A-and I mean the child ending up in the government institution, not in some other family.

---

I found word `disown`, but that is about family link ending, not about child joining the orphanage.
Similarily - `abandon`

Answer (score 2):

Parents can *give up a child for adoption*. I am not aware of any shorter expression.

Answer (score 2):

In American English, the common expressions are either to **give up** the child for adoption, or **put up** the child for adoption.

For example:

> [Giving a baby up for adoption in New York or New Jersey allows you to make a loving and secure plan for your child if your circumstances make it hard, or impossible, for you to parent a newborn.](https://adoptionlawny.com/pregnant-considering-adoption/overview/)

> [Putting your baby up for adoption can give them a loving family, a safe home and a bright future.](https://www.americanadoptions.com/pregnant/adoption_process)

Comment: I've seen 'hand over' as well.